# Is the new Vegeta god of destruction transformation a recycled version of the original Super Saiyan 3 transformation that didnt happen?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

I've seen some fans commenting this, the new Vegeta god of destruction transformation, it is the original design of the Super Saiyan 3 transformation. Then, the Super Saiyan 3 transformation was modified and it ended being what we currently now. I think I've seen years ago a video about the original Super Saiyan 3 transformation being different, so I think those commentaries are believable, but I have no proof of it.

(Probably colored to a different color)

[image]

Is the new Vegeta god of destruction transformation a recycled version of the original Super Saiyan 3 transformation that didnt happen?

Comment: I found some original concept art of ssj3 and it hard short hair just like that so I'm gonna say it might be the recycled ssj3 form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the picture below, [found on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dbz/comments/atnl7g/original_concepts_of_majin_buu_and_ssj3_goku_from/), one of the first drafts for SSJ3 did look like Ultra Ego somewhat, with spikier hair and no eyebrows. The picture comes from the [DRAGON BALL 30TH ANNIVERSARY - SUPER HISTORY BOOK](https://artbookisland.tumblr.com/post/154536855350/dragon-ball-30th-anniversary-super-history-book), released in 2016.

[image: A photo of a Dragon Ball book, containing concept arts for Majin Buu, Great Saiyaman and the SSJ3 transformation. Notably, we can see that first drafts for SSJ3 involved short hair with no eyebrows or long hair with a tail ; the final version was a combination of both, long hair with no eyebrows.]